# Prestashop: User information block will not appear

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm using prestashop 1.6. and I'm trying to hook the "user information block" to the hook called "displayTop (Top of pages)". It is hooked up properly, but when I go to the website it does not appear. What could be the problem?

Thank you for your reply